# Ionic 3 ion-list horizontal - want to show a list ion-list horizontal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to use ***Ionic 3*** ion-list (or whatever works in Ionic 3) to show a horizontal list instead of the typical vertical list.

Looking for a solution ***without a lot of css or hard to maintain code.***

```
        <ion-content>

          <ion-list >
            <ion-item *ngFor="let data of dataArray"  (click)="dataDetail(data)">
              <ion-thumbnail item-left>
                <img src="https://data.url.com/{{data.path}}{{data.photoName}}"/>
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
              <p>{{data.details}}</p>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>

        </ion-content>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks
Phil

Comment: If putting `oyl-list {display: block; width: auto; float:left;}` in your component's scss is a lot and hard to maintain, by all means, don't. Btw: you might even get away without the width and display thingie...

Comment: damn, replace "oyl-list" by "ion-item", I just c&p'eed from my code without paying much attention and Stackoverflow only lets me edit during 5 minutes... :-$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in this way. This works for me.

HTML

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-33 *ngFor="let post of list">
 <div class="card card-1" (click)="ondemand_details(post.product_final_categories_id)">
   <img src="{{post.product_final_categories_icon}}">
    <p style="font-size: 9px;">{{post.product_final_categories_name}}</p>
   </div>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

And SCSS is:

```
img1 {
border: 2px solid #BA55D3;
border-radius: 50%;
padding: 5px;
width: 50px;
background-color:#4B0082;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px yellow;
}
.card {
 background: #1E90FF;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 7px;
 margin: 1rem;
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 }
.card-1 {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
 transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  }
 .card-1:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  }
```

You can change the code according to your needs. If you face any problem please let me Known.

Hope this will help You.

**Update horizental scroll**
Html:

```
 <ion-content padding>
<ion-item>

   <ion-scroll scrollX style="height:100px;">
  <div class="scroll-item">
  <ion-col col-33 *ngFor="let post of list">
 <div class="card card-1" (click)="ondemand_details(post.product_final_categories_id)">

   <img src="{{post.product_final_categories_icon}}">
    <p style="font-size: 9px;">{{post.product_final_categories_name}}</p>
   </div>
    </ion-col>
   </div>
   </ion-scroll>

</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Add SCSS:`

```
ion-scroll[scrollX] {
white-space: nowrap;
.scroll-item {
display: inline-block;
}}
```

I have tested it in my project, and it works fine. it will show output something like this.

[image]
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try it.. It does not scroll like the list does but It does show up as Horizontal which is cool.

Comment: how do I make the Horizontal grid scroll thru the list? right now it only shows 4 of the 21 results in the list.

Comment: hi, @philipfwilson I updated horizontal scroll. I have tested in my project and its working fine.

Comment: working on this today. I will get back to you soon. Thanks Phil

Comment: One more question.. how do I reduce the vertical spacing on the list. There is a lot of space on the top of this list.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample.html:-    
<ion-content>

        <ion-scroll scrollX style="height:220px;">
          <ion-card class="scroll-item" padding *ngFor="let test of testlist"> - you will here dynamic list

            <--You will set here your list-->
            <ion-row style="font-size: 25px;">
             <p *ngIf="test.cust_name"><b> {{test.cust_name}} </b></p>  
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
              <p *ngIf="test.demo_car_id">{{test.demo_car_id[1]}}</p>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
             <p *ngIf="test.location"> {{test.location}} </p>
            </ion-row> 
          </ion-card>
        </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>

In the above list set as per your list. I was used ioncard inside ionscroll. 

sample.scss:-
ion-scroll[scrollX] {
        white-space: nowrap;
        .scroll-item {
        display: inline-block;
        }
    }

Thats all. Enjoy your coding.
```