# Ionic horizontal reordering list

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-list

I am developing a simple ionic v4 application, and I have created this simple ionic reordering list:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)" disabled="false">
       <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
           <ion-label>
              {{item}}
           </ion-label>
           <ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder>
       </ion-item>
   </ion-reorder-group>
</ion-list>
```

Is there a way to show horizontally the items inside the list instead of the typical vertical style, manteining the reordering feature?

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993221/ionic-3-ion-list-horizontal-want-to-show-a-list-ion-list-horizontal

Comment: @Sam thank you for your reply! Unfortunately this does not help me because I need, not only to show the items on the list horizontally, but also to preserve the possibility of rearranging them by drag and drop.
Can you suggest me a solution to do these two things?